# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError how to resolved this error

Tags: java, hibernate, servlets

when i submit the registration form Registration servlet run but when i created an object of session factory of hibernate it give me an Exception ."javax.servlet.ServletException: Servlet execution threw an exception
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)".Please help me to find from this exception.

```
package login;

import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;

@WebServlet("/Registration")
public class Registration extends HttpServlet {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public Registration() {
    super();
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}


protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String username =  request.getParameter("username");
     String password =  request.getParameter("password");
     String name =  request.getParameter("name");

     User u = new User();
     u.setUsername(username);
     u.setPassword(password);
     u.setName(name);

     SessionFactory sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();

}
```

Comment: post the stacktrace in full

Comment: Please provide complete stack-trace as well jar file name which are in the classpath as well as the tomcat version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add latest `hibernate.jar` in your class path

Comment: Thanks for u r suggestion rehman. i  already added latest version of hibernate jar but it getting same error .

Comment: Where did you add it ?inside `WEB-INF\lib` ?

Comment: try to open your `lib` folder inside `target` folder and check whether that jar is present or not

Comment: @Rehman How you know which class gave this NoClassDefError, OP has not even provided the stacktrace.

Comment: As per Rahul's comment it started throwing exception when he created object of  `SessionFactory` and those classes(`SessionFactory` and  `Configuration`) comes under same jar file .